# Use Firebase Messaging variables in PCL project

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How do I use Firebase Messaging variables in a PCL project in Xamarin?

I want to subscribe to a topic when a certain condition is true. This condition is based in the PCL project.

How do I do this in a PCL project for example?

```
if(a == b)
{
    FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("test");
    lbl.x.Text = "Subscribed to test";
}
```

I can only use `FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("test");` in the Android project, so how do I access it in the PCL project?

Answer (score 0):

You not need to write this code in PCL project because this is project specific code not shared code.

Subscribing topics is different for Android and iOS project. For more information yu can visit samples [here.](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make it so that whenever a condition in the PCL project is true, only the android project subscribes to a topic? I want to do this in the PCL, because I don't know how the android project works. There are no pages, so how do I access a label from XAML code from the PCL project?

Comment: If it is working then fine but good to have this code in android project.

Comment: I am not saying it is not working. Please read my comment  :). Moreover you can go through samples I have provided. You should do it in your Application class. Add new class(In Android project) inherit that with Application.